# Invalid bash variable assignment

Tags: command-line, bash

I have two scripts namely `variables.sh` and `install.sh`. When I execute `bash install.sh`, the `.config` file is not properly created. The `export CC` line doesn't adds `BUILD64` variable entry into it and misses to add the `"` at the end of the line.

Snippet of `variables.sh`:

```
INSTALL_DIR="/tmp/panda64"
TARGET="x86_64-panda-linux-gnu"
BUILD64="-m64"
CC="${TARGET}-gcc ${BUILD64}"
```

Snippet of `install.sh`:

```
cat > "${INSTALL_DIR}/.config" << "EOF"
#!/usr/bin/env bash
EOF

echo "export INSTALL_DIR=\""${INSTALL_DIR}\""" >> "${INSTALL_DIR}/.config"
echo "export TARGET=\""${TARGET}\""" >> "${INSTALL_DIR}/.config"
echo "export BUILD64=\""${BUILD64}\""" >> "${INSTALL_DIR}/.config"
echo "export CC=\""${CC}\""" >> "${INSTALL_DIR}/.config"

source "${INSTALL_DIR}/.config"
```

Snippet of `.config`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export INSTALL_DIR="/tmp/panda64"
export TARGET="x86_64-panda-linux-gnu"
export BUILD64="-m64"
export CC="x86_64-panda-linux-gnu-gcc
```

I tried using `shellcheck` program to see where I've been going wrong. But it also doesn't points out my mistake. I would appreciate if someone would point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try instead

```
cat > "${INSTALL_DIR}/.config" << EOF
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export INSTALL_DIR="${INSTALL_DIR}"
export TARGET="${TARGET}" 
export BUILD64="${BUILD64}" 
export CC="${CC}"
EOF

source "${INSTALL_DIR}/.config"
```

you should still get variable expansion inside the heredoc, but you can get rid of messing quoting.

Comment: You will need to use `EOF` without quotes to get variable expansion within the here doc

Comment: @steeldriver I just tested now and you are right. I assumed bash here docs treated `"` the same as  in echo etc.

Comment: No problem - test before post is my motto ;)

Comment: So the first EOF needs quotes in your answer, the second does not? Can you confirm, or better just edit your anwer?

Answer (score 2):

try running your scripts through bash's explaination mode  -x

```
bash -x install.sh
```

This will show the return values of commands and the contents of variables which will highlight where you are going wrong.